# Install LibreOffice 3.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, libreoffice

For security testing purposes, I need LibreOffice 3.5.0 on an Ubuntu 16.04 version. Unfortunately, I tried to get it from a publicly available repository and there is no more deb for 3.5.0 (it has been removed).

```
wget http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/3.5.0/deb/x86_64/LibO_3.5.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-
```

Does anyone knows from where I can get it?

Answer (score 0):

I just found /old repo instead /stable.

```
http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/3.5.0.3/deb/x86_64/
```